# shorten axios text/html response

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, axios, screen-scraping

I am sending an Axios request to a web page for scraping a little string off of it, but the returned response is a large html, and I only need a little part of it, is there a way to somehow shorten the response so I can save data and make the request faster?

```
const longHtml = await axios.get('https://example.com');
const shortHtml = longHtml.data //get short data here
```

Comment: what do you mean by `a little string off of it` ?

Comment: i mean, i want to take an "innerText" of an element in that webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what your trying to do, you wan't to stop the request when you find the data you want, you could use [htmlparser2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser2) and feed it a stream from axios and then register listeners and when you get the element you need you can end the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Web scraping is a technique used for retrieving data from websites. You fetch the page's contents, and after that extract the data you need from the page.

here an example by using axios and [cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/)

```
const axios = require("axios")
const cheerio = require("cheerio")

async function fetchHTML(url) {
  const { data } = await axios.get(url)
  return cheerio.load(data)
}
const $ = await fetchHTML("https://example.com")

// Print the full HTML
console.log(`Site HTML: ${$.html()}\n\n`)

// Print some specific page content
console.log(`First h1 tag: ${$('h1').text()}`)
```

Comment: thank you, the answer helps, but what i wanted was knowing whether or not it is possible to fetch a small portion of the html, so i make the request a little faster, but with your response i assume that it is not possible, but that's fine.